# The specified network name is no longer available

Tags: windows-7, windows, home-networking, windows-home-server

I'm trying to transfer files from my windows 7 machine to my self built windows home server (old dell 4550). The WHS is the default install except Whiis add-on is installed. I also installed and uninstalled firefly media server add-on, and added two external usb 2.0 hard drives

When I try to copy files, they will start copying then hang until I get this error "There is a problem accessing \server\folder"

When I try to copy via command line, it will copy 2-3 files then say "the specified network name is no longer available" then copy a few more and repeat. this happens with the copy and xcopy command.

I running a 10/100 netgear 24port switch (unmanaged) and linksys WRT54GL flashed with the tomato firmware. cat5e cables.

I have already tried all the basics I could think of like changing cables ports making sure both NICs are set to auto negotiate. Mapped the share as a drive. updated all drivers. uninstalled and reinstalled drivers.

Any body have any ideas?

Comment: Can these files be be copied inside the Windows 7 machine?

Answer (score 2):

It disappeared for my when I disabled "network discovery" on Win7.
I noted regular network disconnections of Win7 when it says "connected" or "identifying" repeatedly.

Here's a [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20120908035639/http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Enable-or-disable-network-discovery) (via the Internet Wayback Machine) to Microsoft instructions about how to turn network discovery on and off in Win7.

Plus, just in case that link gets broken, here's a screenshot of what it said on 2012-Sep-08:

[image: screenshot of referenced webpage with instructions]

Comment: In case anyone wonders, here's instructions about [how to turn network discovery on and off](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Enable-or-disable-network-discovery) in Win7.

Comment: @martineau That link is broken now

Comment: @HackSlash: I updated Algirdas's answer to rectify that.

Answer (score 1):

This often indicates a hardware problem with the disk(s) and/or disk controllers (I get this problem with faulty RAID controllers frequently).  Check your server's event logs to see if you have any messages to that extent and run some hardware diagnostics on your server.

In response to your comment:
There are usually diagnostics that you can run in your computer's setup (BIOS), check your manual or look on Dell's site for instructions for those.  Dell also has a [**list of tools**](http://support.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/dsn/en/document?c=us&docid=316675&l=en&s=gen) that you can use to perform diagnostics from within Windows.

Comment: I checked the event viewer and this message came up a lot "persistent drive letter service failed" What do you recommend for hardware diagnostics? FYI, I'm a programmer, not a network/sys admin :)

Answer (score 1):

It might be useful to keep a '`ping`' running between the machines when you try this out.
If there is a network path problem, ping will show a glitch,
else, you need to start looking at the server machine hardware.

This will keep running at one probe per second till you stop it.

> `ping -t server`

since this is local network, the 'time' should also remain constant;
a varying response time also implies network trouble

Answer (score 0):

Clair, sounds to me like you are having a hardware failure.  More specifically, the HDD in the WHS.  I would suggest that you replace that drive ASAP and get your data off of it.

Answer (score 0):

I recently got this error while attempting to access a system using UNC path to the hostname. I found that I could access it via IP address but not hostname. I tested DNS and DNS is working fine.

This Fails:

```
\\hostname\c$\
```

This Works:

```
\\111.222.333.444\c$\
```