# Network share not always available on Windows 2003

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, windows-server-2003, samba

we have a windows 2003 server with a shared directory/folder. 
I've seen this thread but this wasn't any help: [The specified network name is no longer available](https://superuser.com/questions/58890/the-specified-network-name-is-no-longer-available)

I have a ping -t running from 3 pc's (vista and two windows 7)
they all work.

the problem occurss when two users enter the network share
then this 'network share is no longer available' appears and the explorer windows turn white.
after f5 or refresh the shared directory is back.

this is really strange. there is no anti virus or kasparsky running on either end.

this is all in the same LAN. the internet connection is really stable, so it's really strange. because a stable internet connection should imply that the local network connection is also stable and that this is a windows issue.

can it be a router issue? I have checked the eventlog on the server for diskfailure related messages, but there are none.

**EDIT:** can this be related to mapping a shared directory to a drive letter? and that there is a router between me and the mapped network drive? or is it just windows that is not working well with two users on the same shared folder? should I install samba or something?

**Edit 2:** can this be related to the fact that I added 'file server' as role through the 'manage server' option. I am removing the role now to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that shared folder has a user limit specified?

You can check that (on Windows 2003) using 
Computer Management->System Tools->Shared Folders->Shares->[Your Share]->Properties->Check User Limit.

Comment: hello vadmyst, there is no user limit. it is set to maximum. though thanks for your answer!